# Transition и width:auto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Конечно я понимаю что данное свойство не работает с width: auto, но я хотел узнать как бы это красиво оформить без данных окончательной ширины блока.

```css
.fdate_post {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 34px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 74px;
    height: 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.4s;
    }
    .fdate_post:hover {
    width: auto;
    transition: 0.4s;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="fdate_post">Ноя 08, 2015  //  
     <a class="post-edit-link" href="edit">Редактировать</a>  //  
     <a href="delete">Удалить</a>
</div>
```

white-space использую для того что бы слова находились на своем месте при анимации, а не выскакивали только когда им хватит места, ибо выходят некрасивые прыжки. Остальное понятно. Все работает только я известной окончательной шириной, но там может поменяться и нужно сделать универсальный инструмент, что бы он подходил как сейчас так и потом. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для такого типа задач отлично подходит max-width/max-height. Анимация правда будет не самой плавной, но частично решит задачу. И советую поставить display: inline-block, потому как в случае с block будет расстягиваться по max-width как-будто параметр задан width. [Вот пример](https://jsfiddle.net/c8w04fc8/). [1](https://jsfiddle.net/c8w04fc8/)

```
.fdate_post {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 1s ease;
    box-shadow: -12px 0 10px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;
}

.fdate_post:hover {
    max-width: 600px;
    transition: 1s ease;

}
```

Comment: Анимация вроде даже плавная, вопрос почему оно зависает в конце? Когда отводишь курсор оно не сразу уходит назад, а ждет около полусекунды. А на счет inline-block то без разницы, у меня float: right там стоит, так что контент все-равно по содержимому обтекает.

Comment: Ну вот про это я и говорю. Видимо браузер просчитывает "конечные координаты" ширины. И поэтом выходит такой "эффект".
UPD можно убрать ease.

Comment: Пожалуй это потому что я не заметил второй transition. Все, ну мягко говоря, нормально. Отличный вариант пока что ибо не очень много лишнего кода.

Comment: Обновил fiddle. сейчас плавнее.

Comment: Вот мой вариант, мне пока нравиться: https://jsfiddle.net/2d9e4zdh/1/